# Creating a new user in a django project is not working properly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have a user project where users can create a profile. After registration the user is created in the backend but it returns an error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
```

The user is logged in but I don't know the reason and how to fix this error.
Here is the models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

here is the views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Here is the urls.py in the main project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('post.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password-reset............)
]
```

here is the template:

```
{% extends "post/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form action="profile" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

What is the reason for directing to `Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/` and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error is showing

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
```

then it is probably looking for url in this location.

In your url configuration it is written as:

```
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
```

So I would recommend trying adding account:

```
    path('accounts/profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
```

Answer (score 2):

In your form, your `action` **should be**:

```
<form action="/profile/" method="POST">
```

and **not**

```
<form action="profile/" method="POST">
```

also **it should** **not** **be**

```
<form action="profile" method="POST">
```

It's not redirecting to the correct address without forward slash `/` before the action's address, because it uses your current page as your base url when `/` is not provided.

Comment: @dmitryo hi I added the action but still nothing happened. Is this the form you are referring to ?

Comment: @Shiko Your base url must be `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, not `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts`, so if your paths are properly configured, you should not be hitting `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts` - it should be `<form action="/profile" method="POST">`, not `<form action="profile" method="POST">` - with `/` before `profile`. The transition to `/accounts/profile` happens because you're at the page with address `/accounts` at the time when you're submitting your form, so you need it to be `/profile` to prevent this.